# Java RMI application doesn't quit

Tags: java, rmi

I have a Java RMI application. The issue is that when I invoke RMI methods, and then finish the code. The application does not end.

In command line, "Bye" message is shown, but it doesn't show the prompt line.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    ...
    System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
    s = (Registry) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost/Registry");
    ChatClientImpl c = new ChatClientImpl(name);
    c.act(s);
    System.out.println("Bye"); <-- "Bye" message is shown
}
```

I have to ^C to make the application stop.

The act() method parses use's input to invoke other methods. However, even when I just quit without invoking any other methods, Java doesn't quit.

What might be wrong? Do I need to call extra methods in order to quit RMI applications?

Comment: The JVM will terminate when all none-daemon threads have finished.  RMI is running it's own threads to manage the system, which will keep the JVM alive

Comment: @MadProgrammer : So, there's no way to the app other than ^C?

Comment: @prosseek `System.exit(0)` may work, but there may be a better way...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: System.exit(0) works, so could you answer it so that I can accept it unless better answer comes up.

Comment: @prosseek I'd like to see if a better answer comes up first ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer RMI threads don't keep JVMs running except for listening threads for exported remote objects.

Comment: @EJP I using "RMI" as an umbrella statement, referring to the overall API, probably not the best choice, but when you see a house, that's what you call it ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer The issue here is not 'RMI's own threads'. It is the exported remote object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `ClientImpl` is a remote object and it is still exported, so the JVM won't exit until you unexport it, with `UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject()`.

If that's so, I don't know why `ClientImpl` even *is* a remote object. You're not doing anything remote with it. You're not doing anything remote with *anything* here except the Registry. I think you have something back to front. You should be calling remote methods on the remote object `s` that you looked up.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to **not calling** remote methods with the object **s**.If you do that remote object will be unexported automatically